# Page object design pattern in multiple projects

Tags: design-patterns, selenium

We test using selenium and use a page object design. That is, we have a library file that contains all the functionality of a certain page on our site. By "functionality" I also mean processes - we have a "Page Object" library for "Login", "Register",... which aren't really pages.

The problem starts when we have multiple projects with the same functionality. For example, we have a mobile version of our site, an ipad version,... The high level process stays the same (for example, to login, you still: 1) fill in username 2) fill in password 3) click enter) but the xpaths change between the sites. In most cases the tests are the same except for a very small number of differences (for example, in login-mobile, you don't have 4) tick remember me).

We have a solution (I'll illustrate the main idea bellow) that involves inheritance of page objects. I'd be happy to hear how you tackle this problem.

Our solution:

- We rap the selenium object with an object we call user
- Every project gets it's own user: i.e., mobileUser, ipadUser, etc.. They all inherit from a parent (abstract) user.
- Our library files are classes that inherit from one another.
- Since the "main" script is the same for the all the projects, we call the same piece of code for each project, giving it a different type of user each time.
- Since there is a user per project, we "import" the correct library file through the user

For example:

```
def testLogin(user):
    user.lib.Login.LoginAction("username", "password")
```

The library name is "Login" and the function we want to call is "LoginAction". If `user` is a mobileUser then `Login` will be the mobile Login library. If `user` is an ipadUser it'll be the ipad Login library, and so on.

Although it seems we've figured out the solution to this problem, the code that comes out is a bit spaghetti-ish. I'd be happy to hear of suggestions of how to improve and how you tackle the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and our way was inheritance. Create few common classes as super classes and whenever you want to make the small changes extend it and create the child class with new XPATHs. 
We also tried to use java reflection to solve the multiple classes overhead, but since we are primarily a QA team we were not comfortable with reflection.